# WinHttpRequest.Option(EnableCertificateRevocationCheck) gives "5: Invalid prodecure call or argument (-2417210492)"

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use WinHttp in VBA code in excel to send an HTTP request.
(The code is actually part of the VBA-Web library, that I am using.)

However, when I try to set the option to check for certificate revocation, I get an error:

```
Err.Number: -2417210492 (0x80042b04)
Err.Description: 5: Invalid procedure call or argument
```

This is the relevant code and the error happens at the last line:

```
Set web_Http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
web_Http.Option(web_WinHttpRequestOption.web_WinHttpRequestOption_EnableCertificateRevocationCheck) = True
```

(`web_WinHttpRequestOption_EnableCertificateRevocationCheck` is a constant with value 18.)

This happens only on some computers but works fine on others.

The error seems to indicate that the Windows/WinHttp version does not support that specific option, but according to the [docs I found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttprequestoption), it really should be supported:

- Windows 7 Service Pack 1
- winhttp 6.1.7601.24000 (according to "properties" dialog of Windows explorer)
- Excel 14.0.4760.1000 (32bit)

Comment: You can try to use XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @RonanVico Thanks! That's not really an option though, because the VBA-Web library does tons of additional stuff, that I would have to replicate (proxy handling, json (de)serializing, authentication, support for MacOS, ...) (Besides I would probably also have to deal with other incompatibilities in between different windows versions myself.)

Answer (score 0):

> This happens only on some computers but works fine on others.

This could be related to your problem. Check the Windows versions that it isn't working on.

[KB4512508](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4512508/windows-10-update-kb4512508)

> After installing this update, applications that were made using Visual Basic 6 (VB6), macros using Visual Basic for Applications (VBA), and scripts or apps using Visual Basic Scripting Edition (VBScript) may stop responding and you may receive an "invalid procedure call error."

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is something we really need to be aware of. In this case, however, it is Windows 7 (see my original post) and either way, we noticed this issue even before this windows update was even released.